# Render XAML inside Direct3D in Windows Store App

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, direct3d, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I would like to render XAML to texture/bitmap and draw the texture/bitmap inside Direct3D (for example, place it on a cube side).

To achieve that on Windows Phone I could use **UIElementRender**. It produces texture, which can 
be drawn anywhere in 3D world (XNA).

Is it possible to do the same thing in Windows Store App?

**SwapChainBackgroundPanel** is not very suitable because it only allows overlaying XAML over Direct3D surface, but not rendering XAML to texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be interesting, but I don't believe it is supported. The 3 available interop mechanisms are only for rendering DX in a XAML app, not the other way around.

If the only thing you want done is to apply 3D transforms to your elements - there is a [Projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.projection) property that is of Projection type which could be a PlaneProjection that supports basic translate/rotate transforms or Matrix3DProjection which you can use to apply any 3D matrix transforms.